# Passing unique pointer to function in a lambda capture

Tags: c++

I have a setup with a minimal reproducing example shown below.

Base class A is pure virtual and the two derived classes have different versions of a function `d()` that is supposed to do some operations.

I use the factory function `choose_operation` to choose between class `B` and `C` at runtime, and it returns a `std::unique_ptr<A>`. Then I use a `std::for_each`, and I need to pass the correct version of `A::d()` into `std::for_each`, and from there onto a function `do_stuff()` which does more work.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cmath>

struct A {
    A() {};
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual double d(double x) = 0;
};

struct B : A {
    double d(double x) override { return std::sqrt(std::abs(x)); }
};

struct C : A {
    double d(double x) override { return std::abs(x); }
};

std::unique_ptr<A> choose_operation(std::string s) {
    if (s == "B") {
        return std::make_unique<B>();
    } else {
        return std::make_unique<C>();
    }
}

double do_stuff(double x, const std::unique_ptr<A>& dfun) {
    x -= 2;
    return dfun->d(x);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> v {3, -4, 2, -8, 15, 267};
    auto dfun = choose_operation("B");

    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [dfun = std::move(dfun)](double& x) {
        x = do_stuff(x, *dfun);
    });

    return 0;
}
```

It is necessary for me to use `std::for_each` rather than a range based for loop, because I will eventually use `std::execution::par` from the `<execution>` header to run the loop in parallel. I have however omitted that for clarity in this question.

I compile it with `g++-13 -std=c++23 main.cpp`, but I get essentially the same issues using clang.

Here is the error message:

```
main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:39:25: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const std::unique_ptr<A>&' from expression of type 'A'
   39 |         x = do_stuff(x, *dfun);
      |                         ^~~~~
main.cpp:29:53: note: in passing argument 2 of 'double do_stuff(double, const std::unique_ptr<A>&)'
   29 | double do_stuff(double x, const std::unique_ptr<A>& dfun) {
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
(base) oyss@eduroam-193-157-178-185 BayesMallowsCpp % g++-13 -std=c++23 main.cpp -ltbb 
main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:39:25: error: could not convert 'dfun.std::unique_ptr<A>::operator*()' from 'A' to 'std::unique_ptr<A>'
   39 |         x = do_stuff(x, *dfun);
      |                         ^~~~~
      |                         |
      |                         A
(base) oyss@eduroam-193-157-178-185 BayesMallowsCpp % g++-13 -std=c++23 main.cpp       
main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:39:25: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const std::unique_ptr<A>&' from expression of type 'A'
   39 |         x = do_stuff(x, *dfun);
      |                         ^~~~~
main.cpp:29:53: note: in passing argument 2 of 'double do_stuff(double, const std::unique_ptr<A>&)'
   29 | double do_stuff(double x, const std::unique_ptr<A>& dfun) {
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

Can someone please help interpret the error message, and suggest appropriate ways of passing the unique pointer into the lambda capture?

I also should add that the object `dfun` is used other places in the code, so simply putting its definition inside the lambda body is not a good solution.

Comment: `*dfun` is an object of type `A`. Pass plain `dfun` instead.

Comment: When captured as you did, `dfun` is of type `std::unique_ptr<A>`, not `std::unique_ptr<T>*`. You just don't need to deference it, see https://godbolt.org/z/cfv5317hr

Comment: I don't see the point of moving ownership rather than capturing a reference. And if you're planning to reuse `dfun`, you must retain ownership outside the l;ambda.

Comment: @some-programmer-dude, passing plain `dfun` works, but it fails when I add `std::execution::par`. I'll update the question in a sec.

Comment: Please  don't change the question too much (to be about something different), post a new question instead.

Comment: Indeed @some-programmer-dude, here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77845658/passing-unique-pointer-to-function-in-a-lambda-capture-for-parallel-execytion

Comment: `do_stuff` doesn't transfer ownership, better to take `/*const*/ A&` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*dfun` is a object of A, it does not comply with the rule of virtual inheritance, just use `dfun` is ok, you can use the following code to test, have a good day:D.

```
 std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](double& x) {
    x = do_stuff(x, dfun);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
 });
```